# firebase realtime database Standard Transaction vs Custom Transaction

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, transactions

I would like to know if the custom transaction can be used instead of the standard one. Is there a data corruption problem using the second method?

If for example my counter is at 0 and two people at the same time increase it to 1. Is the counter corrupted or a request is queued and executed later?

rules

```
".write": "data.val() == null && newData.val() == 1 || newData.val() == data.val() + 1"
```

standard transaction

```
const db = firebaseApp.database();
const ref = db.ref().child('node/counter');

ref.transaction(count => {
    if (count === null) {
        return count = 1
    } else {
        return count + 1
    }
});
```

custom transaction

```
const customTransaction = async (retry = 10) => {
  const db = firebaseApp.database();
  const ref = db.ref().child('node/counter');

  for (let i = 0; i < retry; i++) {
    try {
      const snapshot = await ref.once('value');
      const counter = snapshot.val() ? snapshot.val() : 0;

      await ref.set(counter + 1);

      return counter + 1;
    } catch (e) {
      if(i >= retry - 1) {
        throw new Error(e);
      }
    }
  }
}

try {
  await customTransaction(20);
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e);
}
```

custom with multiple counters

```
const customTransaction = async (retry = 10) => {
  const db = firebaseApp.database();
  const ref = db.ref().child('node/');

  for (let i = 0; i < retry; i++) {
    try {
      const snap = await ref.child('counter').once('value');
      const snap1 = await ref.child('counter1').once('value');
      const snap2 = await ref.child('counter2').once('value');


      const counter = snap.val() ? snap.val() : 0;
      const counter1 = snap1.val() ? snap1.val() : 0;
      const counter2 = snap2.val() ? snap2.val() : 0;

      const paths = {};
      paths['node/counter'] = counter + 1;
      paths['node/counter1'] = counter1 + 1;
      paths['node/counter2'] = counter2 + 1;

      await db.ref().update(paths);

      return {
        counter: counter + 1,
        counter1: counter1 + 1,
        counter2: counter2 + 1
      }
    } catch (e) {
      if(i >= retry - 1) {
        throw new Error(e);
      }
    }
  }
}

try {
  await customTransaction(20);
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e);
}
```

Comment: Why are you trying to implement custom transaction mechanism here?

Comment: because if i use multipath update i can increment more counters at once. is the final result the same? or there are more risk in this way?

Comment: i've updated the example with multiple counters

Comment: At first glance that custom multi-node update looks OK, and your security rules will ensure that each node you write to is increased by one or set to 1 (the && and || is a bit hard to scan, so you might want to add parenthesis). But "is it secure" or "is it the same" are really hard to answer. What specific concern do you have about the code+rules?

Comment: my main concern is about data corruption. If two clients update the same counter at the same time with the same value what happen? with transaction they are ordered then one of them will be rejected and incremented again. With my custom transaction is the same? I dont understand if transaction is just a client side mechanism or there is also server side logic.

Comment: Since you're reading the value, and basing the updated value on that, one of those updates will fail if the reads overlap.